# @ApiResponses and @ApiResponses in swagger

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have annotated my method like,

```
@ApiOperation( value = "Get time spent on category", response = CategoryBean.class, responseContainer = "List", notes = "API to get the time spent on all tasks based on category" )
@ApiImplicitParams( {
        @ApiImplicitParam( name = "x-auth-token", value = "", dataType = "string", required = true, paramType = "header" ) } )
@ApiResponses( value = {
        @ApiResponse( code = 200, message = "Success", response = CategoryBean.class, responseContainer = "List" ) } )
@RequestMapping( value = "/getTimeSpentOnCategory", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public ResponseEntity<?> getTimeSpentOnCategory( @RequestBody DashboardTaskRequestBean bean )
{/**some operation**/}
```

But in my swagger UI, I'am not able to get the Status code 200 and its message. Please explain why?
The following picture is the snapshot of the UI,
[image]

Comment: Where is the problem? At the top you see the status 200 with example value under Model Schema. At the bottom you see other possible codes.

Comment: By the way, to the other question you have posted, please accept/upvote the answer if my answer clarified your question. That encourages developers to respond to questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: Where is the `message` displayed which I configured for code 200?
And, I have up voted the answers, but I'am short by 1 point of reputation, so it won't be reflected. So, please up vote my question, if you feels it is valid.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue and looks like it is fixed with version 3.0.

As I see it, you are able to see the response structure at the top, but it is not visible in the table at the bottom of the screenshot.

This is also raised here and is fixed with version 3.0 :

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1505

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1297